# Is it better to rely on react-ids or classes when parsing websites?

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm writing a piece of code that will be, regularly, going on some specific website and fetch few data for post anlysis usage. To do so, I'm using ccs selectors and I have to choose between html classes and React-ids. For ease of maintenance I want to use css selector that would change, hopefully, very less often. So which is better for this purpose: html tags (the classes name could change at any time) or React-ids ?

Assume this is my `html` doc :

```
<a class="BoxAll" reactid="11.0.7">
       <span class="BoxAllLabel" reactid="11.0.7.0"> Box1 </span>
      <span class="BoxAllLabel" reactid="11.0.7.1"> Box2 </span>
</a>
```

And I have those css selectors:

```
class_css = "a.BoxAll"
react_css = "a[reactid='11.0.7']"
```

Which one is it better to use for maintainability issues ?

PS: I'm working on `Python`, with `Selenium` and `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0):

if any locator contains **numeric**, then you should avoid it as much as possible.

I would recommend you to go with `class name` , if you compared it with react id. Most of the time they are developed **dynamically** , so better to avoid this.

For this **HTML** :

```
<a class="BoxAll" reactid="11.0.7">
       <span class="BoxAllLabel" reactid="11.0.7.0"> Box1 </span>
      <span class="BoxAllLabel" reactid="11.0.7.1"> Box2 </span>
</a>
```

**css selector :**

```
a.BoxAll  [for anchor tag]
a.BoxAll>span:first-child   [first span tag]  
a.BoxAll>span:nth-child(2)   [second span tag]
```

**XPATH :**

```
//a[@class='BoxAll']  
//span[contains(text(),'Box1')]  
//span[contains(text(),'Box2')]
```

Better to use **css selector** with `^ , * , $` , to match **prefix, contains and suffix**